# Plot several lines in bokeh applet

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I want to extend the [sliders applet](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/sliders_applet) example of the bokeh-website.

How can I "freeze" the current setting of the line and draw a new line in the same plot?

I am thinking in introducing option-boxes to change between the lines further down the road but so far I can't even get several (static) lines into the same "line" object.

If anyone knows some more documentation about the "bokeh widgets" that would be great, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the callback (in this case, `input_change`) you can do whatever you like, including creating new `ColumnDataSource` objects, or calling new render functions like `line`. Another option would be to start with a single `multi_line` renderer in the setup step. For this renderer, the data stored in the `ColumnDataSource` is a not just a list of numbers, it is a "list of lists of numbers". So every update you could append a new sublist of `x` and `y` values to the existing data source.

If you'd actually like help iterating on a real example, I encourage you to visit the Bokeh mailing list or GH issue tracker where you can have more of a back and forth exchange with Bokeh devs.